# ASP.NET site takes 10 seconds to load basic Hello World page but is instant on second load

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5

I have a ASP.NET program that works just fine but takes 10 seconds to load the default.aspx page, if I close the browser and quickly reopen the browser and enter the same URL then the page loads almost instantly. I have compiled my code and published the site so it contains dlls so it shouldn't need to compile. This delay is problem for me as my program is designed to get the data as quickly as possible.

My test.aspx page contains the code below. I have a placed this page within my programs web site so it is using the same web.config.

```
<%@ Page Title="Test" Language="VB" %>
<html>
<head runat="server"></head>
<body><h2>Hello</h2>
<p><%Response.Write(now())%></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me remove the startup delay?

Many thanks
James

Comment: Definitely sounds like it is compiling on the fly.  It's been too long since I used ASP.NET last, but I'd check again to make sure you have pre-built everything.

Comment: I'm relatively new to ASP.NET, I see no .cs files in my published site just .aspx pages and dll files. Is this compiled? I assumed it was. Thanks

Comment: .aspx files still need to be compiled - so depending on how many of them you have that could be taking some time.  In my experience the application isn't going to start 'instantly' even if it's precompiled - although it would be a lot faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your application pool idle timeout settings in iis

Answer (score 3):

Even if the code is compiled it will still need to be loaded, possibly into a new application domain which might be taking some time.

One solution is to keep the application alive by regularly pinging the website from an external service.

E.g. [www.keepaliveforever.com](http://www.keepaliveforever.com)

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy answer, you'll probably need to look at a stack trace to figure it out. Observe what code is running and how much time it is taking to execute.  Remember, the first time you visit your site your application has to load into memory and various things are happening in the background.

Comment: Is there any setting that can keep it in memory? After a minute or so it again takes 10 seconds to load. If I can change a setting that would change this time out to 8 hours that would be fine.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to guarantee it stays in memory.  App domains in IIS are supposed to be recyclable - for example an exception in your app could cause the app domain to be shut down (although in this case it will probably be restarted).